# Creating API responses with flask-restless

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restless

Let's say I have two models in SqlAlchemy:

- `UserType`
- `User`

`User` has a foreign key to `UserType`

I have properly configured flask-restless to serve these models as API endpoints:

- `/api/user`
- `/api/user_type`

But by default, when I visit either of these endpoints, I get the related data associated with each object in the response:

- Each `User` has the corresponding `UserType` object nested in the response
- Each `UserType` has a collection of `User` nested in the response

This will definitely lead to a lot of overhead as the data grows a lot. If I just want to GET  the list of `UserType` that the system supports, all of the associated users will come back. Usually an API would generate a link for related resources:

- `/api/user/1/user_type`
- `/api/user_type/1/users`

Has anyone gotten these links out of flask-restless responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue that has been active on GitHub for a long time. Not sure if the developer is planning on fixing it or not:

https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/168#issuecomment-69821642

I ended up going with `flask-restful` and building my own endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This is now implemented as of release **0.17.0**

If your `User` model looks as follows:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    user_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user_type.id"))
    user_type = relationship(UserType, backref=backref('users'))
```

and your `UserType` model looks like:

```
class UserType(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
```

Then you can fetch all `users` of a specific `user_type` by issuing a GET request to...

**/api/user_type/1/users**

...where the suffix **/users/** is designated by the `backref=backref('users')` attribute passed to `relationship()` for the *user_type* column in `User`, and **1** is the `id` of the *user_type* being queried.